Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for finding cliques missing a few edges?
The Bron-Kerbosch algorithm takes a graph and finds its maximal cliques in an efficient manner (as far as I'm aware, it is $O(3^{n/3})$, where $n$ is the number of vertices).
Let $t$ be a positive integer. I am interested in finding $t$-almost-cliques, that is, induced subgraphs which would be cliques if it wasn't for $t$ or fewer missing edges. Ideally I would like $t$ to depend the size of the almost-clique, but we can fix it for simplicity.

Is there a variant of the Bron-Kerbosch for $t$-almost cliques?

Even a reasonable algorithm would be appreciated.

Augment your graph with $t$ edges and apply the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm as a blackbox.

@codeR which $t$ of the $n \choose 2$ edges should be added?

For a fixed $t$, there are a finite number of $O(n^{2t})$ possibilities. Why not evaluate all of them? The complexity only grows by a polynomial factor. This is, ofcourse not efficient, but one way to solve it.

One trivial DP Algo has $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ time complexity, which also gives all the $t$ values for all possible subgraphs

@codeR Thank you, that's helpful! Additional idea: in the case that $t$ depends on the size of the almost-clique, one can do this for $t=0,1,...,N$ and then filter out the cliques that are missing too many edges in the original graph. It seems to me that this should still be $O(n^{2N}3^{n/3})$, right?

@EnEm This was my first thought as well though it seems the augmentation idea might be a bit faster
